# How to get value from two table if id is same in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am very new in sql, then i am so confused how to get join or get value from two.

First table:

```
ID  P_ID Name   AGE U_ID
1    5    B     8    5w
2    8    D    17    6j
3    7    R    67    0qw
```

Second Table:

```
 ID  P_ID   Address   Edu
    1    6    Bddd     +2
    2    7    Dssss    Bachelor
    3    2    rress    Phd
```

Here, i want to get accorading to P_ID, but i have U_ID only.
For this:   Let us assume that now I have **U_ID=0qw**.

How to get value from second table. **Address** and **edu** , and **Age** Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can study sql from [w3schools#sql_joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join on the column that both tables have in common.

```
select t1.age, t2.address, t2.edu
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.p_id = t2.p_id
where t1.u_id = '0qw'
```

Then use the table names or alias names (like `t1` for `table1`) to pick columns from the tables you join.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking forward to this:

```
SELECT t2.Address, t2.Edu, t1.Age 
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN secondTable t2
ON t1.P_ID = t2.P_ID
WHERE t1.U_ID = '0qw'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT table1.AGE
     , table2.Address
     , table2.Edu 
  FROM table1 
 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.P_ID = table2.P_ID) 
 WHERE table1.U_ID = '0qw';
```

**NOTE:** SQL query is not case sensitive.